# How do I use experimental standard library features?

Tags: c++, c++14

This [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental) describes (draft) technical specifications for proposed features. Some of them have been voted out of C++14 like `any` and `optional`, which look like their respective Boost counterparts. Like the `tr1` header files, I thought I could include `<experimental/any>` to play around with it. But the header file doesn't exist, so I'm guessing it's not implemented.

Are these header files simply theoretical or has any compiler attempted to implement these?

Comment: Maybe it's not implemented *in your compiler*. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: /agreed, check your compiler's "features status" page

Comment: @GregHewgill: You mean implementation. One can use different standard-library implementations with many compilers. Anyway, just use boost.

Comment: Clang's and libc++'s status are http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html and http://libcxx.llvm.org/ts1z_status.html. GCC and libstdc++, as well as VS, should be as easy to find.